# What is the correct grammar to use in this situation? "She and her colleagues" or "Her colleagues and she"?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, pronouns

This is the sentence:

> *She and her colleagues* have been given handmade gifts from grateful patients and offered food and drinks.

Which form is correct?:

- She and her colleagues
- Her colleagues and she

If both are correct, which one sounds better?

Comment: Both are correct. *...her colleagues have* sounds better than *...she have*.

Comment: Grammatically, both are fine. But many grammatical strings are unacceptable or better avoided on other grounds. @Tinfoil gives sound advice.

Comment: "She and her colleagues" is natural. "Her colleagues and she" tastes awful, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing a convention:

*You and your friends are clever*

*He and his friends are clever*

*We and our friends are clever*

*They and their friends are clever*

**But**

***My friends** and **I** are clever.*

The first person inversion "My friends and I" is conventional (and is the only instance that occurs) as it puts the speaker in the lesser position and thus expresses a more modest and polite aspect.

Comment: I'll upvote this answer if you edit it to make explicit that the inversion convention only applies to first person singular subject pronouns, and not at all to any other subject pronouns, and that it's in fact more natural to put a subject pronoun first. Then you'll have answered the question explicitly, rather than by implication.